# Django: how to get template views to display images -- Noob edition

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Note: There are a lot of questions related to this on Stack Overflow. However, this is not duplicate, as it requests noob level explanation (i.e. someone who has completed the Django tutorial).

So I completed the Django tutorial and am off to make my own site to reinforce what I learned (and augment it as well). I wanted to make a site which could display some images of a given object. Since a lot of the before mentioned posts use goods and pictures (e.g. to emulate multiple images for a product on Amazon),  lets go with that for this post as well.

I made myself an app, and am using name-spaced urls and templates (as described in the tutorial).

In addition, following the Many-to-One documentation, I have two models `Product` and `ProductImage` with the latter having a `ForeignKey` to the former.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey("Product", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=product_dir_path)
```

Using a reverse many-to-one monitor (e.g. `aSpecificProduct.productimage_set.all()` ) I grabbed all my images which I set up in a directory under the app's directory `<my_app>/uploads/product_<id>/image_<id>` using the little `upload_to` trick in the [model field reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#imagefield) part of the documentation.

```
 def product_dir_path(instance, filename):
    return "<my_app>/uploads/product_{0}/{1}".format(instance.product.id, filename)
```

Great, so I am all ready to make a view that grabs a specific item, uses the above semantics to get all the images for that item, and use a template view to display those images!

So I put these images into a variable `img_list` and put it into my context, which is passed to `render` as an argument.

I have a loop set up and inside that loop I have

```
<img src="{{img.image.url}}"/>
```

which when inspecting the website I see

```
<img src="<my_app>/uploads/<specific_product>/image_<number>.png"/>
```

awesome!... except for the `404` error.

Now a lot of these other posts talk about setting `MEDIA`, `MEDIA_ROOT`, `STATIC`, in `settings.py` and adding something to the `urlpatterns` (but not specifying if it is the project `urls.py` or the app one...).

There is some other text explaining this, but waaaaay too technical for someone who just completed the django tutorial and has no idea what any of these things do, or why they are needed. To be fair, the `ModelField` reference for `ImageField` and `FileField` do not make it that clear either (at least to me) as to how one would do this (whereas the documentation for Many to One has plenty of examples to figure it out).

So, please, in a tutorial like fashion, what am I missing to getting my images to display? Please be very explicit as to what files are being changes (e.g. `my_site/urls.py` vs `my_app/urls.py`), what these changes do, and why they are needed. Given the host of actual duplicates, it is clear that figuring this out is not!

Thanks

EDIT:

I moved the where the file "uploads" to be under `<my_app>/static/<my_app>` and renamed it to `product_images`. Following the linked page on [static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/) I tried the following. Hardcoding the link works. Using the solution by most of the other posts, does not.

```
<img src="{% static '<my_app>/product_images/product_<id>/<img_file>' %}"/>
```

works but

```
<img src="{{img.image.url}}"/>
```

does not where the latter has `src="<my_app>/static/<my_app>/product_images/product_<id>/<img_file>"`
and the former `static/<my_app>/product_images/product_<id>/<img_file>`

Comment: Just read the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

Comment: @allcaps I understand the app specific static directory as explained in the django tutorial, this does not make sense to me

Comment: @allcaps, I followed that doc page, and I still get 404

Comment: @allcaps also I a pretty sure this has a quote related error `src="{% static "my_app/example.jpg" %}"`

Comment: Nope, that is correct template code. No errors. Please post any errors if you have them.

Comment: Did you solve your issue? Just debug step by step. Save an image to the ImageField. See what ProductImage.objects.last().image.url returns. See if the file is on disk. See if you have an url pattern that serves that file. Check if you can open it in a browser. Check if you add ProductImage.objects.last().image.url to view context this var is available in the template and renders the correct path. If this all works, only then try the backwards relation by passing a Product to your template and do `{% for img in product.productimage_set.all %}<img src="{{ img.image.url }}">{% endfor %}`

Comment: Note: files uploaded to image fields are user uploaded content by convention these files live in the media dir in your project root. User interface files are considered static files and are most app based and therefore live in a static dir inside your app(s). During development Django development server can serve them from their original location. In production environments you want to do python manage.py collectstatic to copy all static files to a static dir. By convention a dir in you project root called static.

Comment: @allcaps to be frank I have read the docs, I have mirrored the docs example and it does not work when translated to my project. I am currently in development mode. My files are under the app in a static directory. As django is not serving them up. `print(ProductImage.objects.last().image.url)`  results in `my_app/static/my_app/product_images/product_<id>/<image_file>`.

Comment: @allcaps I have tried `{% static ... %}` and just `{{img.image.url}}` neither works.

Comment: In Python, what does `ProductImage.objects.first().image` give? And `ProductImage.objects.first().image.url`?

Comment: It gives the image object and my_app/static/my_app/product_images/product_<id>/<image_file‌​> respectively

Comment: There is a difference between STATIC and MEDIA. The stuff you store in a model is MEDIA and should NOT live in app but in the project root. I told you before. Anyway, there are too many questions like yours on SO. Only by pointing out your mistake you're question will be answered. But how to do that? You can't debug it, how can I? How can anyone on SO? We need *all* your code and a running project. You say that you read and copied the documentation, but you obviously made a mistake somewhere. Believe me when I tell you the docs are right. People use the docs as a reference each day.

Comment: When debugging you should always look at each step in the process. Break it down to the smallest pieces of functionality and see if they work. One by one. Untill you narrowed down the problem. If you doubt the `product_dir_path` (I doubt all code you supplied) take it out completely and replace it for something simpler. Like the docs say: `upload_to='uploads/'`.

Comment: I created a example project for you. Both STATIC and MEDIA work. https://github.com/allcaps/myproject/tree/master/myapp

Comment: @allcaps I appreciate your assistance. I do not claim that the docs are wrong - just that some parts are not necessarily accessible after completing the short Django tutorial

Comment: I find your question interesting as so many people ask assistance on SO. Will you answer your own question once you figured out what went wrong?

Comment: @allcaps yes, I was aware about this prior to posting - hence the noob edition. Hopefully, when I figure this out, we can at least have a solid clear answer to help newcomers like myself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make certain changes to your mysite/urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [

]


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, 
document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings.py file

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static_cdn')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'media_cdn')
```

Comment: what and why is there a media folder that isnt in a new project? (remember this is noob edition)

Comment: I can not accept the answer as it does not address the full context of the question.